# http server is up, some services report it down

Tags: apache-http-server, raspberry-pi, http, raspbian, lamp

I have an HTTP server which is up and running (and accessible), but some services report it down (isitup, IFTTT which I need it to connect to).

Ping shows it up also.

I have NO firewall running and have no idea what might be causing it.

it's lamp on Raspbian, I can provide extra details with pleasure.

Where can I start my check? what other details do I need to inspect?

Cheers, Dor.

Comment: How did you ping it? Using an external or internal source? Which services report it as up?

Comment: external of course, several online ping services. and well, I'm not sure who reports it up, but is accessible from external sources. I have no idea where to start and investigate.

Comment: OK - all services report server is down, but it is accessible from several sources. where do I start?

Comment: when you say accessible, do you mean the server or the service? for instance your webserver and HTTPd are running if you get a HTTP 50x error, but most services see that as being offline, since the service you are trying to provide isn't working for anyone.

Comment: no, http 200 status is being returned from a simple static html page. any ideas? i'm clueless.

Comment: Perhaps the routes being taken are different? It is possible for computers that communicate to take different paths (one of which may be bad). So a site can appear offline to someone in one area (wherever your 3rd-party sites are located), but not to another (wherever you are locally to your Pi).

Comment: What did you use fort the external ping? How can you be unsure who is reporting it as up or down if you did the testing yourself/got the reports? What sources are able to access it?